# Как распарсить сложную строку?

Tags: python

Есть строка, которую нужно распарсить:

```
from typing import List
def parse_str(st:str) -> List[str]:
    return # смотри пример
```

Пример работы функции:

```
st = 'op:dsafllksaf cl:lsdfjlal;sdf op:laksdjfljsa op: alsdfjl;ksadjf;l cl:asdflkj'
parse_str(st)
>>> ['op:dsafllksaf','cl:lsdfjlal;sdf', 'op:laksdjfljsa',
     'op: alsdfjl;ksadjf;l', 'cl:asdflkj']
```

Единственное до чего я дошел - это распарсить его используя регулярки `re.split('op|cl', st)`. Но это возвращает не то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рерулярке вполне такое взять под силу.

```
import re
def parse_str(st):
    return re.findall(r"(.+?:.+?)(?:\s+|$)", st)
```

Или через тот же `re.split()`:

```
def parse_str(st):
    return re.split(r"(?<!:)\s+(?!:)", st)
```

```
['op:dsafllksaf',
 'cl:lsdfjlal;sdf',
 'op:laksdjfljsa',
 'op: alsdfjl;ksadjf;l',
 'cl:asdflkj']
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо большое!